# How to get the Uploading images height and width using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

In this case i am uploading an image using HTML and JavaScript.

I need to upload an image with only in the size of width->400 and height->400.

How can this be done using java script.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't upload using pure JavaScript, server side code must be involved as well. So, what's your server side language?

Comment: PHP is my server side language

Comment: you have this in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php use it to get the image dimensions, and if not valid cancel the upload.

Comment: Also, can't see how this question is related to JavaScript.. please explain or remove that tag to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can with Javascript (maybe with HTML5?). Regardless, you wouldn't want to do input checking on the client side because users (not all) are malicious or perhaps could just javascript blocked.

A better "solution" is to let them upload it, check the width and height of the picture, and if isn't what you want then present a message to the user like "Error: Picture is too big, decrease picture size!"

Or another solution would be to scale it for them to that size once they upload it.

Comment: The HTML5 option would be [the File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), not widely supported yet.